# Finding the reason behind the value of the integral.

Tags: definite-integrals

I was just trying to find $$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2}\frac{\sin{9x}}{\sin{x}}\,dx $$ using an online integral calculator. And surprisingly I found that if I replace $9x$ by $ x,3x,5x$ which are some odd multiples of $x$ the value of integral came out to be $\dfrac \pi 2$.

I can't figure out the reason and would like to know why this is happening.

---

**Edit**: It can also be noted that $$\int_{a{\pi}}^{b\pi }\frac{\sin{9x}}{\sin{x}}\,dx =(b-a){\pi}$$ where $a,b$ are integers.

Comment: The following identity seems like it may help:$$\frac{\sin((n+1/2)\theta}{\sin(\theta/2)}=1+2\cos x+2\cos(2x)+\cdots+2\cos(nx).$$ (This is known as the Dirichlet kernel, and a proof may be found at the corresponding Wikipedia page [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel#Proof_of_the_trigonometric_identity).)

Comment: I think the statement about the integral from $a\pi$ to $b\pi$ is incorrect. Setting $a=\frac18$ and $b=\frac16,$ Wolfram Alpha says the integral is a negative number, not $(\frac16-\frac18)\pi.$ Did you mean to say instead that $a$ and $b$ are integers?

Comment: @David I checked for few other rational a and b and they satisfied but you are right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Hint

> Consider $I(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} dx$

$$I(2m+1)-I(2m-1)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2m+1)x-\sin(2m-1)x}{\sin{x}} dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2\sin(x)\cos(2mx)}{\sin{x}} dx$$
$$\implies 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(2mx)dx.......(1)$$
Now think what happens to this integral when $m$ is an integer.
And also try to use the fact $I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**Edit**
(As OP has changed the question a bit)

> Now consider$I(n)=\int_{a\pi}^{b\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} dx$

From(1) $$\implies 2\int_{a\pi}^{b\pi} \cos(2mx)dx=2\bigg[\frac{\sin(2mx)}{2m}\bigg]_{a\pi}^{b\pi}$$
$$\implies I(2m+1)-I(2m-1)=\frac{1}{n} \bigg[\sin(2\pi bx)-\sin(2\pi ax)\bigg]=0$$
Provided ${a,b} \in \mathbb{Z} $
$$\implies I(2m+1)=I(2m-1)$$
Now As $I(1)=(b-a)\pi$

Hence

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]
{\int_{a\pi}^{b\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} dx=(b-a)\pi
}
$$
When n is odd.